Inconsistency in transition rate derivation in "Introduction to the Quantum Theory of Scattering" by Rodberg and Thaler
I've been working through the derivation of the transition rate in the book "Introduction to the Quantum Theory of Scattering" by Leonard S. Rodberg and R. M. Thaler (Chapter 8, Section 4 "The Cross Section", pages 225-226, freely accessible on ResearchGate), and I think I've come across an inconsistency.
I'm hoping someone can help me understand where I might be going wrong or if there is indeed an issue with the derivation in the book.
According to Eq. (4.1), the overlap between the initial state $\phi_f$ and the time-evolved state $\psi_f(t)$ is:
$$\langle\phi_f | \psi_I(t)\rangle = \langle\phi_f |\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}(\hat{H}_0 - E_i)t\right] \psi_i^{+}\rangle = \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}(E_f - E_i)t\right] \langle\phi_f | \psi_i^{(+)}\rangle$$
The transition rate is defined as the time derivative of the absolute square of this overlap, as given in Eq. (4.2):
$$w_{fi} = \frac{d}{dt} |\langle\phi_f | \psi_I(t)\rangle|^2$$
However, when taking the absolute square of $\langle\phi_f | \psi_I(t)\rangle$, the time-dependent phase factor cancels out, leaving a time-independent probability:
$$|\langle\phi_f | \psi_I(t)\rangle|^2 = |\langle\phi_f | \psi_i^{(+)}\rangle|^2$$
Consequently, the transition rate should be zero. Yet, the authors proceed to derive a non-zero expression for the transition rate in Eq. (4.5).
Is there an error in the derivation, or am I misinterpreting the equations?
Source: Rodberg, L. S., & Thaler, R. M. (1967). Introduction to the Quantum Theory of Scattering. Academic Press. (Pages 225-226, Section 8.4 "The Cross Section")


You misunderstood the equation. If you only used Equation (4.1), then you will not have a V term inside the bra-ket. Equation (4.3) used the time derivative, which is why it has the V term.

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks! Is there any problem of using Eq 4.1 to calculate the overlap? Also, according to Eq 4.4, the absolute square of the overlap seems time independent, if $ i \neq f$.

It turns out that the author doesn't include the $i\varepsilon$ factor in the evolution. If added, one has
$$
|{\psi_I(t)}\rangle = \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}(\hat{H}_0 - E_i + i\varepsilon )t\right] |\psi_i^{+}\rangle
$$
which more naturally leads to the expression of transition rates.
